# Wait for a task do be done in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, nsurl

How can I wait for a certain task to be done?

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]];

if (!data) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NOCONNECTIONALERTTITLE] message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NOCONNECTIONALERTMESSAGE] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NOCONNECTIONALERTCANCELBUTTON] otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
} else { ... }
```

This `if` is always false, since its called before data even is initialized. I'm 100% sure, that the connection is established.

I want to use this as an easy alternative to checking the internet-connection programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

`dataWithContentsOfURL:` is a blocking call, so `data` is initialised when you try to use it. If it's nil then you likely have an issue with the URL you're trying to load.

Because this is blocking you shouldn't use it on the main thread. And, generally, you shouldn't want to wait for completion - you should embrace the asynchronous nature of network operations and use appropriate asynchronous API and designs to handle them.

Log the `NSURL` that you are creating to check it exists (and fix if it doesn't).

---

Your simplest option for running an asynchronous download and handling the result is to use `NSURLConnection +sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`. Supply the queue as `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` so that your callback is run on the main thread and you can update your UI.

Comment: youre right! my bad! can you tell me more about async tasks in ios?

Comment: Added a simple option to the answer. There are many options depending on the details of what the request and response are and what you are going to do with the result...

Comment: its basically a task that grabs a JSONArray from a certain URL.

Comment: If you're using it for `checking the internet-connection` then you don't want to download any data (or only a byte)...

Comment: no not really, I'm using it to download something from my database. so I need it.

Comment: Ok, then I'd most likely suggest that you look at RestKit.